# Access filter form using combo box with numerical values

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access Database with a continuous form called "releases_form". The form has a field called "Term" that has numerical values. I want to add a combo box called "term_filter" that can be used to  filter the form. When you select a term in the combo box, the form should display any values that are greater than or equal to the value in the combo box.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
Private Sub term_filter_AfterUpdate()
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[Term]>= & Me.term_filter & " '"
End Sub
```

I get the following error:

```
Run-time error '3075':

Sytnax error (missing operator) in query expression '[Term]>=& Me.term_filter &'.
```

I've gotten this far by trying to adapt the code from similar questions on Stackoverflow but I'm stuck at this point. I'm no good with VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[Term] >= " & Me!term_filter.Value & ""
```